# Switched shared PCL to target .NET Platform Standard, now receive BadImageFormatException

Tags: coreclr

I have a PCL that I was going to use in a asp.net core project.  On the PCL project I viewed the Properties > Library  and clicked "Target .NET Platform Standard". This went down hill fast.  I quickly reverted all my changes using TFS.  Now, even though TFS is showing no changes to my project, if I try to run a WebApi 2.2 project (within the same solution) that depends on the PCL, I get this error:

[image]

edit: If I publish the web api project to IIS it works, so its just debugging that is broken.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: yes, cleaned, restarted iis express, restarted VS...I think I remember running in to something like this before and it had to do with asp.net cache, but clearing that didn't help either.